# Cocos2d-X Widget Image from Texture2D?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I've been using a method in for Cocos2d-x to create a Sprite from a png file. Then I take that Sprite, calculate the size of the box, and scale the image up or down so that I only need to use one size of image assets for all size devices my app will run on. This is because I can use RenderTexture to render a new Texture2D on the spot.

With a Sprite, I can simply apply that Texture2D to it. However, I am using the newer Widgets for Cocos2D-X as my HUD, namely Buttons. It seems like the only way I can set the images for a button is via a string.

So my question is: is there a way to get my newly created Texture2D into a string format that would work in this situation? I wouldn't think so, but thought I would ask. And if not, maybe someone knows a way to do this without simply switching from the Button widgets to Sprites? Would simply save time and keep my code neater if I didn't need to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've looked into .h file and I don't think it's possible, but I've found these methods:

```
void loadTextureNormal(SpriteFrame* normalSpriteFrame);
void setupNormalTexture(bool textureLoaded);
void loadTexturePressed(SpriteFrame* pressedSpriteFrame);
void setupPressedTexture(bool textureLoaded);
void loadTextureDisabled(SpriteFrame* disabledSpriteFrame);
void setupDisabledTexture(bool textureLoaded);
```

the problem these aren't public (protected). 
As for SpriteFrame you can create it from texture.
So maybe you can subclass button and use these method to initialize it.